# Errors appear on clicking any non-submit button (Angular Reactive Forms)

Tags: html, angular

I am using angular 7 and material design toolkit. I have a form which has multiple validations and two buttons; One is for opening the file picker ('upload image' button) and other is for submitting the form .Whenever I click the 'upload image' button, whose 'type' is unspecified,all the validations/errors in the form instantly appears on the corresponding fields.Is there anyway to avoid this?

This is the HTML code for 'upload image' button:

```
 <input 
    style="display: none" 
    type="file" (change)="uploadFile($event)" 
    #fileInput>
    <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="fileInput.click()">Select File</button>
   </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a `button`'s `type` is not specified and it's found inside a `form`, it is automatically treated as `type=submit` button. You need to specify `type=button` if you do not wish it to trigger the submit mechanism.

```
<button mat-button type="button" color="primary" (click)="fileInput.click()">Select File</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the button type as `button`, under a `form` a button  with no type is considered as `Submit`.

```
<button type="button" mat-button color="primary" (click)="fileInput.click()">Select File</button>
```